# How would I print two diagonals of a square?

Tags: python, matrix, diagonal

So for a example, if a user had input 2, the output will be `xo ox` and if the user inputs 3 it will output `xox oxo xox` etc. The code I have so far only outputs the diagonal of a square in the opposite direction.

```
size = int(input("Size of the square: "))

for i in range(size):
    line = ""

    for j in range(size):
        if i+j == size-1:
            line += "x"
        else:
            line += "o"

    print(line)
```

In this example, when you input 3 for example, you will get as an output:

```
oox
oxo
xoo
```

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track, but you've only accounted for one diagonal. Have you tried accounting for the other one in a similar manner? In other words, what condition defines the top-left -> bottom-right diagonal?

Comment: Yes so for the other diagonal, I made so that i == j as the condition for the if statement it would accumulate the x values

Comment: All right, so did that not work?

Comment: Ahhh I just realised that it was an elif statement you had to use rather if, I derped out haha.

Comment: You can use an `if` and and `or`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size = int(input("Size of the square: "))

for i in range(size):
    line = ""

    for j in range(size):
        if i == j:               # main diagonal
            line += "x"
        elif i + j == size - 1:  # secondary diagonal
            line += "x"
        else:
            line += "o"

    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy [fill_diagonal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) for a more efficient approach

```
size = 3
a = np.chararray((size, size))
a[:] = 'o'
np.fill_diagonal(a, 'x')
np.fill_diagonal(np.fliplr(a), 'x')
```

output

```
a = chararray([[b'x', b'o', b'x'],
               [b'o', b'x', b'o'],
               [b'x', b'o', b'x']], dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're in love with generators

```
square = "\n".join(["".join(["x" if i == j or i == size - j - 1 else "o" for j in range(size)]) for i in range(size)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using one loop as follows:

```
size = 3
result = []
for x in range(size)[::-1]:
    line = list("o" * size)
    line[x] = "x"
    result.append("".join(line))
print(*result)
```